# git is not finding remounted USB drive which contains a bare repository

Tags: git, macos, usb, git-remote

I started a bare repository on a USB drive so I can have good version control over multiple machines.

After cloning the USB repository on a machine (mac) I removed the usb and continued working on the cloned, local copy. I then remounted the usb to the machine and attempted to push my work on the usb. However, this error appears when I try to push

```
git push usb master
fatal: 'usb' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Which I think means that git is not finding any remote repositories. and when I tried, `git remote` no remote repositories appear. I also made sure I remounted the USB on the same port but the issue persisted. Do I need to somehow re establish a connection?

Comment: Well.... remote should be there. As long as it's not there, you won't be able to push into another repo, no matter where it is.

Comment: @eftshift0 It is there. If you read carefully I said I remounted the USB.

Comment: But then you also said "_I tried, `git remote` no remote repositories appear_". The usb can be mounted, but the repo can't just guess that there's a repo that it can use as a remote. A remote has to be set up pointing to the USB repo on that repo that you are working on.

Comment: @eftshift0 yes you are right which is exactly what I am asking. How shall I make the connection again once I mount the usb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the USB repo remote and then you could push to it:

```
git remote add myUSB /path/to/usb/repo
# then you could do
git fetch myUSB
git push myUSB some-branch
```